# Spring ScriptUtils: with MySql causes tests to freeze forever

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I am trying to execute different sql scripts depending on the active profile (h2 or mysql) in Spring Boot test environment. Here is the test case I am trying to perform with MySql which causes the freezing:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace= AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class EntityRepositoryTestIT {

    @Autowired
    EntityRepository entityRepository;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
    private String profile;

    @After
    public void after() throws Exception {
        ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(dataSource.getConnection(),
                new ClassPathResource("/scripts/test_data_clear_"+profile+".sql"));
    }


    @Test
    @Sql(scripts = "/scripts/test_data.sql", executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD)
    public void findAllTest() throws Exception {
        Assert.assertEquals(7, entityRepository.findAll().size());
    }

}
```

Logger on org.springframework.jdbc with DEBUG enabled shows that freezing occurs on the invocation of this line:

```
ALTER TABLE entity AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

This only fails with MySql, whereas with H2 works fine:

```
ALTER TABLE entity ALTER COLUMN id RESTART WITH 1;
```

The test works fine again with MySql **ONLY** by using annotation:

```
@Sql(scripts = "/scripts/test_data_clear_mysql.sql", executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD)
```

Seems like @sql annotation adds some more logic than programmatic invocation of ScriptUtils does. With H2, both ScriptUtils and @sql annotation work smoothly.

**The problem is the annotation doesn't allow the dynamic change of executed sql script, its 'scripts' parameter is a compile time constant.**

Any suggestions on how to make it work will be very appreciated!

Comment: Can you post your database configuration beans / application.yaml (database config only).

Answer (score 2):

My gut feeling is that you're simply not closing / returning database connections properly.

```
@After
public void after() throws Exception {
    try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
        if (connection != null) {
            ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(connection,
                new ClassPathResource("/scripts/test_data_clear_"+profile+".sql"));
            log.info("SQL script successful");
        } else {
            log.warn("!!! No connection available !!!");
        }
    }
}
```

i.e. wrap your connection in a `try-catch-resources` block so that the connection will be closed (and be returned to a pool if you're using database pooling e.g. Hikari).